# CakePHP 4 datetime migrations error 'Incorrect datetime value'

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing an app in PHP 7.4 (cakephp 4.4).

I am trying to use migrations to properly update my tables using cakephp bake migrations feature, but I have an issue with datetime columns.

Here is my code :

```
bin/cake bake migration AddInvitationTokenToUsers invitation_token:string:unique invitation_token_expires_at:datetime
```

The output :

```
Creating file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/config/Migrations/20230416152709_AddInvitationTokenToUsers.php
Wrote `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/config/Migrations/20230416152709_AddInvitationTokenToUsers.php`
```

And then I launch the migration :

```
bin/cake migrations migrate
```

And I have this error :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'invitation_token_expires_at' at row 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php:192
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php(192): PDO->exec('ALTER TABLE `us...')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Util/AlterInstructions.php(108): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->execute('ALTER TABLE `us...')
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php(626): Phinx\Db\Util\AlterInstructions->execute('ALTER TABLE `us...', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php(1001): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->executeAlterSteps('users', Object(Phinx\Db\Util\AlterInstructions))
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/AdapterWrapper.php(477): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->executeActions(Object(Phinx\Db\Table\Table), Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/TimedOutputAdapter.php(420): Phinx\Db\Adapter\AdapterWrapper->executeActions(Object(Phinx\Db\Table\Table), Array)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/AdapterWrapper.php(477): Phinx\Db\Adapter\TimedOutputAdapter->executeActions(Object(Phinx\Db\Table\Table), Array)
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Plan/Plan.php(151): Phinx\Db\Adapter\AdapterWrapper->executeActions(Object(Phinx\Db\Table\Table), Array)
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Table.php(719): Phinx\Db\Plan\Plan->execute(Object(Migrations\CakeAdapter))
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Table.php(627): Phinx\Db\Table->executeActions(true)
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Table.php(152): Phinx\Db\Table->update()
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/config/Migrations/20230416144739_AddInvitationTokenToUsers.php(27): Migrations\Table->update()
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Migration/Manager/Environment.php(108): AddInvitationTokenToUsers->change()
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Migration/Manager.php(388): Phinx\Migration\Manager\Environment->executeMigration(Object(AddInvitationTokenToUsers), 'up', false)
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Migration/Manager.php(359): Phinx\Migration\Manager->executeMigration('default', Object(AddInvitationTokenToUsers), 'up', false)
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Console/Command/Migrate.php(122): Phinx\Migration\Manager->migrate('default', 20230416144739, false)
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Command/Phinx/CommandTrait.php(37): Phinx\Console\Command\Migrate->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Command/Phinx/Migrate.php(85): Migrations\Command\Phinx\Migrate->parentExecute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(298): Migrations\Command\Phinx\Migrate->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1040): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(301): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Migrations\Command\Phinx\Migrate), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Command/MigrationsCommand.php(126): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/BaseCommand.php(189): Migrations\Command\MigrationsCommand->execute(Object(Cake\Console\Arguments), Object(Cake\Console\ConsoleIo))
#24 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Command/MigrationsCommand.php(198): Cake\Console\BaseCommand->run(Array, Object(Cake\Console\ConsoleIo))
#25 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php(334): Migrations\Command\MigrationsCommand->run(Array, Object(Cake\Console\ConsoleIo))
#26 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php(172): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->runCommand(Object(Migrations\Command\MigrationsMigrateCommand), Array, Object(Cake\Console\ConsoleIo))
#27 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/bin/cake.php(12): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->run(Array)
#28 {main}
```

My migration file is like this :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class AddInvitationTokenToUsers extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * More information on this method is available here:
     * https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#the-change-method
     * @return void
     */
    public function change(): void
    {
        $table = $this->table('users');
        $table->addColumn('invitation_token', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('invitation_token_expires_at', 'datetime', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addIndex([
            'invitation_token',
        
            ], [
            'name' => 'UNIQUE_INVITATION_TOKEN',
            'unique' => true,
        ]);
        $table->update();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on the reason of this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Your columns are set to not allow nulls, but to default to null. What value are you expecting to be set in any existing rows when these are added?

Answer (score 0):

Your `sql_mode` config probably doesn't allow zero dates, check [**how `NO_ZERO_DATE` works**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date).

Since you have existing rows in your tables, you should either provide a valid datetime default value for the new column according to your DBMS configuration (for example `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`), or make the column nullable.

Since the column is an expiration time for tokens, you most likely don't want to set a datetime value as the default, so you'd go for the latter, ie change the value for the `null` option to `true` to make the column nullable and thus use `null` as the default.

Answer (score 0):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html:

The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Your '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is less than the supported values.